# Дата в базу ложится не правильно, на 1 день меньше указанной в шаблоне

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-jpa

Подскажите пожалуйста. Я так понимаю проблема в JPA? До метода save() дата выводится такая же какая введена в шаблоне Thymeleaf, а уже в базе дата на 1 день раньше. Как ее решить?

Часть кода контроллера:

```
@PostMapping("/new_violation")
        public String saveViolation(
                @Valid @ModelAttribute("violation") Violation violation
        ) {
            System.out.println(violation.getDateProtocol());
            violationService.save(violation);

            return "/new_violation";
        }
```

В сервисе:

```
@Service
public class ViolationServiceImpl implements ViolationService {
    private final ViolationRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    public ViolationServiceImpl(ViolationRepository repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Violation violation) {
        System.out.println(violation.getDateProtocol());
        repo.save(violation);
    }
```

В репозитории:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import ru.asu.pdn.model.Violation;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public interface ViolationRepository extends JpaRepository<Violation, Long> {
}
```

Ну и кусок из шаблона на всякий случай:

```
<td th:text="${#dates.format(violation.dateProtocol, 'dd.MM.yyyy')}">Дата протокола</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем помогло следующая строка в .properties: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?useSSL=false&&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow`
Надеюсь кому-то поможет